# Abort an Ajax Request in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have been working with ExtJS 6.0 . I use Ajax Request to retrieve data from application server. In my current view onClick of OK button, am making Ajax call by passing payload to the service. At the same time am masking the screen with cancel button on it. Sometime service takes time to respond. user may thinks to redefine his search by clicking cancel button and do the action again. I used to  unmask the screen when click of cancel in masking screen but Ajax is not getting aborted. it loads the old data as soon as service respond. is ther any way to stop/abort my old ajax request?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var requestId = Ext.Ajax.request({...});

Ext.Ajax.abort(requestId);
```

Comment: or just `requestId.abort()`. It gets more complicated if you need to cancel form submit with file upload.

Comment: I have to abort by ajax request whenever i click cancel  button in masking screen. There is a handler for cancel to unmask the screen. but how do i abort request when cancel button is clicked

Comment: Note that although you can abort the request as mentioned here, the server will still be processing the request and will eventually return to a client that is no longer listening.  You may want to handle this as well if that is a concern.